# Python code to search string from Json file not working

Tags: python, json

Please see below file Apps.xml:

```
{
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : ""
    }
  },
  "_embedded" : {
    "platform_applications" : [ {
      "uuid" : "abc",
      "id" : 312155,
      "name" : "ABC",
      "linked_scan_target_url" : ""
    }, {
      "uuid" : "def",
      "id" : 320915,
      "name" : "DEF"
    }, {
      "uuid" : "efg",
      "id" : 375935,
      "name" : "EFG",
      "linked_scan_target_url" : ""
    }, {
      "uuid" : "hij",
      "id" : 398364,
      "name" : "HIJ",
      "linked_scan_target_url" : ""
    }, {
      "uuid" : "jkl",
      "id" : 630286,
      "name" : "JKL",
      "linked_scan_target_url" : ""
    }, {
      "uuid" : "lmn",
      "id" : 726470,
      "name" : "LMN",
      "linked_scan_target_url" : ""
    } ]
  },
  "page" : {
    "total_elements" : 6,
    "total_pages" : 1,
    "size" : 50,
    "number" : 0
  }
}
```

Problem statement: Need to find "uuid" for given "name" e.g. if name:ABC we should get corresponding uuid:abc

Code:

```
 appfile = "/app/data/Apps.xml"
 with open(appfile) as f1:
    data1 = json.load(f1)
 print("File:",data1)
 for item in data1['_embedded']:
     print("JSON",item)
     for subitem in item['platform_applications']:
         print("JSON",item['platform_applications'])
         if subitem['name'] == app_name:
           print ('uuid', item['uuid'])
           app_uuid = subitem['uuid']
```

> Error:
> for subitem in item['platform_applications']: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Ideally, key "`data1['_embedded']`" should return

```
"platform_applications" : [ {
  "uuid" : "abc",
  "id" : 312155,
  "name" : "ABC",
  "linked_scan_target_url" : ""
}, {
  "uuid" : "def",
  "id" : 320915,
  "name" : "DEF"
}, {
  "uuid" : "efg",
  "id" : 375935,
  "name" : "EFG",
  "linked_scan_target_url" : ""
}, {
  "uuid" : "hij",
  "id" : 398364,
  "name" : "HIJ",
  "linked_scan_target_url" : ""
}, {
  "uuid" : "jkl",
  "id" : 630286,
  "name" : "JKL",
  "linked_scan_target_url" : ""
}, {
  "uuid" : "lmn",
  "id" : 726470,
  "name" : "LMN",
  "linked_scan_target_url" : ""
} ]
```

But it is returning only
" `platform_applications` " and not data inside it.

Could someone please help?

Comment: `app_uuid = next(pa['uuid'] for pa in data1['_embedded']['platform_applications'] if pa['name'] == 'ABC')`…?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the statement

```
'''

for item in data1['_embedded']:

'''
```

item will iterate through the list of key values in the data1['_embedded'] dictionary

so maybe you could prefer doing

```
'''

for item in data1['_embedded']['platform_applications']:
      if subitem['name'] == app_name:
        print ('uuid', item['uuid'])
        app_uuid = subitem['uuid']

'''
```

it iterates through the list of dictionary data in the 'platform_applications' which is what you intended

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for item in data1["_embedded"]["platform_applications"]:
    if item['name'] == app_name:
        print ('uuid', item['uuid'])
        app_uuid = item['uuid']
```